# I'm just running the simple c++ program just to check my mingW is working fine or not but I'm having this error. can someone help me to resolve it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

[Running] cd "c:\Users\ayush\Desktop" && g++ vector.cpp -o vector && "c:\Users\ayush\Desktop"vector
g++: error: vector.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: Have you saved your file? As `vector.cpp`? In the directory where the compiler will look for it (`c:\Users\ayush\Desktop`)?

Comment: is `vector.cpp` located in `Users\ayush\Desktop` ?

Comment: It seems it doesn't find the file. is vector.cpp on Desktop?

Comment: `"c:\Users\ayush\Desktop"vector` should probably be `"c:\Users\ayush\Desktop\"vector` for the execution part.

Comment: it's on the desktop and yes i've saved the file

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and doing these two things resolved the issue

1. Saving the file or enabling auto-save.
2. Disabling the antivirus or adding the folder that consists the program in the exceptions list for the antivirus (if such an option is available).

Comment: Tried both the things, nothing worked. actually it's working when I use cmd

Comment: I faced this problem with Python. The path variable I had set was in the user variables, but when I added the same path variable in the system variables section, the problem was resolved.